# Conformal mapping between intersection of circles to unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I want to construct a conformal mapping of the region $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z - 1/2| < 1 \text{ and } |z + 1/2| < 1 \}$ to the unit disk. I think I would use the Mobius transformation $-\frac{z - \sqrt{3}i/2}{z + \sqrt{3}i/2}$ to map the intersection of the two circles to two lines. Then, somehow I would want to map this to the upper half of the plane, and then use the Cayley transformation to get the unit disk. I'm not sure how to modify this approach and how to get to the upper half of the plane.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One way is to go region -> circular sector -> half disc -> quarter plane -> half plane -> disc.

Comment: How do I determine the size of the sector which the mobius tranform I mentioned maps the region to?

Comment: If by size you mean the radius, it doesn't matter. If you mean the angle (more likely, I think), just look where $\pm \frac{1}{2}$ are mapped to. (Your $\frac{i\sqrt{3}{2} - z}{i\sqrt{3}/2 + z}$ is an excellent starting point, by the way.) Do you know how to finish once you found the sector?